# Acessing custom headers in fetch in React-Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I've read multiple questions about this on stackoverflow. All of them seems to be targeted for fetch usage on browser, so the solutions need cooperation of the server to manage the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` HTTP header. I don't control the server, and I need to read Location, Cookies and other things using fetch. Is it possible?

I need to read `Location` and `Set-Cookie` HTTP headers from server

Answer (score 0):

Current fetch implementation for Android and iOS self manages cookies, you can't directly manage them.

There are java and objective-c patches for this: https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies

(it was just a matter of delivering non standard http header variables wtf facebook)